# How OAuth resource server receives access token?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Oauth2Exp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OauthDemo.class, args);
    }
}
```

and a simple REST end point (retrieves access token and outputs it along with string "Hello world!!"):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SampleRest {
    
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;
    
    @GetMapping("/helloworld")
    public String helloworld(Authentication authentication) {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient =
                this.authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient("google", authentication.getName());

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
        
        return "Hello world!!\n" + accessToken.getTokenValue();     
    }
}
```

Then I have following configuration for configuring this app as OAuth client:

```
@Configuration
public class OauthClientConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
            
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

and following configuration to configure same app as OAuth resource server:

```
@Configuration
public class OauthResourceServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerfilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

application.yml looks something like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: <client-id>
            clientSecret: <client-secret>
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
```

Also I have necessary dependencies for oauth-client and resource server in pom.xml. With all this, it works perfectly fine. The REST endpoint does indeed returns the string made up of "Hello world!!" and access token value:

[image]

Now am guessing where exactly authorization code is exchanged for access code and forwarded to the resource server REST endpoint. OAuth client has the responsibility to exchange authorization code for access token. Whereas, the resource server has the responsibility of validating incoming access tokens. When I hit the URL `localhost:8080/api/helloworld`, I am **directly hitting** `helloworld()` REST endpoint of the **resource server**. Then how it receives access token? Does OAuth client gets invoked before REST endpoint, say in some security filter chain which takes care of exchanging authorization code with access token and then forwards it to the REST endpoint?

Comment: Have a look into the OAuth2 specification: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-7.1 (in request header).

Comment: I believe this is more related to how spring security implements the OAuth than the OAuth standard itself. I want to know how (exactly where in the flow? a method / filter chain) Spring security ensures access token is exchanged with the authorization code and passed to the resource server. Nevertheless, I have gone through substantial amount of the OAuth2 spec and again gone through the part you linked. But unable to figure it out. Please let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Why is it important? It is an implementation detail. All you have to know is the specification. What is acutally your problem, which you want to solve?

Comment: Getting exchanging authorization code for access token is a task of OAuth client. But, when I hit from react app in browser DIRECTLY to the REST endpoint provided by resource server, then OAuth client is not involved in this flow. Still resource server ends up getting access token. This is a bit puzzling!! (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) Other tuts (for e.g., [udemy course repo](https://github.com/simplyi/PhotoAppWebClient/blob/rest-template-example/src/main/java/com/appsdeveloperblog/ws/clients/photoappwebclient/PhotoAppWebClientApplication.java)) which have OAuth client & resource server as a separate spring boot app, have proxy REST endpoints in OAuth client which manually perform exchange of auth code for access token and forward the REST request to resource server with access token. But no such thing is happening here!! Here, we have single spring boot app designated as both oauth client & resource server.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Google client is configured to use the client credentials flow and that flow is being automatically triggered when you inject the authorizedClient. This behaviour is explained in [this Okta guide](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/05/05/client-credentials-spring-security#create-a-resttemplate-command-line-application). To configure a code flow client you would need to set extra details similar to this:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          idsvr:
            client-name: Login with the Curity Identity Server
            client-id: demo-client
            client-secret: Secr3t
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: openid, profile
        provider:
          idsvr:
            issuer-uri: https://idsvr.example.com/oauth/v2/oauth-anonymous
```

**ARCHITECTURE**

Usually there are multiple components involved:

- The resource server (or API / microservice) just does the job of validating access tokens, then serving data to the client. An API endpoint should never trigger a client flow.
- The client is most commonly a separate web or mobile app. It authenticates the user using an authorization server, then receives an access token, then sends it to the API.
- The authorization server is used to issue tokens that your resource server can validate. The example token you have posted is issued by Google but is not meant to be used to secure your own APIs, and you may not be able to validate it.

The [Curity Examples](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oidc-spring-boot/) provide some example clients and APIs. In your case you could maybe look at implementing a Spring API and a Spring website as separate components.

In the early days at least, I would recommend keeping these as separate processes, so that responsibilities are easier to reason about. The Okta example also does this.

Comment: I guess this does not answer my question, right? Let me summarize my question: I have single spring boot app exposing REST endpoints. I added two spring security configurations to it. One applies to URLs `/**` and configures it as OAuth 2 client with `.oauth2Login()`. Another configuration applies to `/api/**`  and configures it as OAuth 2 resource server with `.oauth2ResourceServer()`. Now when I hit resource server URL `/api/helloworld` from browser, corresponding REST endpoint receives access token. But I never invoked OAuth client here, then where exactly access token is obtained?

Comment: I updated my answer - I think your client is not configured to run a code flow - try updating the client configuration, and see my general points.

Comment: In my `OauthClientConfig` class, I have used `oauth2Login()`, whose [doc says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#oauth2Login()): "The "authentication flow" is implemented using the Authorization Code Grant." Apart from that, when I hit REST endpoint `localhost:8080/api/helloworld`, it does redirect to google login, where I have to enter my credentials, which I believe is the indication that Authorization Code Grant is indeed what is happening and not the Client Credentials Flow.